# How can I monitor the bandwidth of an object in the Amazon S3 service?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How can programmatically monitor the bandwidth of an object in AWS S3 service? I would like to do this to prevent excessive bandwidth usage by clients who are using our services and costing us more than we can afford. We like to limit 1TB bandwidth for each object.

Answer (score 5):

The detailed usage reports are just per bucket, not per object.

What you could do is [enable logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) and parse the logs once an hour or so. It's certainly not instant, but it would prevent people from going *way* over your usage limits.

Also, s3stat is a good option up to a point. Once you start doing more than ~ 50 million requests per month, they have trouble crunching the data.