# Cost capping Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service)

Tags: amazon-s3

I find the fact that the service does not offer cost capping a bit scary. Are there alternatives (to Amzn s3 that offers capping), or is there a way to for example poll the current cost and disable the service if data or transfer volumes suddenly grow like crazy?

Or is there some other clever way of capping the bills?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is obviously relevant: [How can I monitor the bandwidth of an object in the Amazon S3 service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283846/how-can-i-monitor-the-bandwidth-of-an-object-in-the-amazon-s3-sevice)

If I understand you correctly, you would like to have an estimate of your bandwith costs + some way of stop people downloading your objects.

For estimating your bandwidth costs, you have two options:

1. Download an usage report from your AWS account; if you choose Data-Transfer-Out and All-Operations there, you can easily get from that a fairly accurate estimate of your bandwidth costs. You have a considerable amount of detail available, but this is a manual process (in spite of *lots* of requests for an API for this at the AWS forums). The closest thing to programmatic access that I've came across is this [script](https://gist.github.com/421559)
2. enable bucket logging, and analyze the logs yourself, or through some external tool/service such as S3STAT.

and concerning blocking access etc,

1. change the object/s and/or bucket/s ACLs from which you're getting most of the downloads, making them private.
2. make your objects available through your own domain, and remap the relevant DNS records for those objects/buckets; you could use AWS Route 53 for this, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the cost of running an EC2 instance accurately to the hour and be pretty sure about your costs.

If you're worried about bandwidth costs you can manage that on your host OS, for example:

https://serverfault.com/questions/52027/how-can-i-limit-per-user-bandwidth

Comment: I don't think this technique applies to Amazon S3.

Comment: I believe with S3 you have no way of limiting bandwith on the server side, other than shutting down the service. Imagine putting up one "attractive" file of 1 GB and getting 10.000 downloads from clients with high-speed connections. Thats 10 TB and a cost of $1500 before you know it.